# Installing Pip but require setuptools and getting syntax error

Tags: python

Trying to install pip without internet, so I downloaded the tar.gz package from pypi.org and when installing the pip setup file by running "python setup.py install" I get "No Module Named 'Setuptools'".

So I downloaded setuptools.tar.gz from pypi.org and ran the "python setup.py install" but this time I get a syntax error. Python version running is 3.5.2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
import setuptools
File "/home/insite/setuptools-57.0.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
File "/home/insite/setuptools-57.0.0/setuptools/dist.py", line 585
license_files: Optional[List[str]] = self.metadata.license_files
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to install setuptools 57.0.0 on Python 3.5. As of [setuptools 51.0.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v51-0-0),

> Breaking Changes
>
> - #2435: Require Python 3.6 or later.

You need a version of setuptools that's 50.0.0 or older.

For what it's worth, the specific error you're getting is because of [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), which was added to Python officially in 3.6. But even if you patched that somehow (and I *don't* recommend trying), you're likely to run into other problems. You just need an older setuptools or a newer Python.

Comment: Yup...figured it out...thanks...sorry for my stupid question...its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong setuptools version was used. Python 3.5 uses setuptools version 50.0.0 or older. Thanks to Silvio Mayolo.